# Delete all attributes but keep specified in html tag with regex

Tags: html, regex, tags

I have html tag like this:

```
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-top:1.0pt;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:1.0pt;margin-left:0in;text-align:center;text-indent:0in;line-height:115%;text-autospace:none'>Something</p>
```

Now, i want to make it like this:

```
<p style='text-align:center;'>Something</p>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: In what language do you want to do this?

Comment: You'd like to do the conversion using javascript or server side language?

Comment: you should not use inline styling rules. try replacing class names that includes these styling rules and just swap class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged regex, here's a regular expression replacement that will match and replace based on what you said:

```
<p class=MsoNormal [^>]*style='[^']*(text-align:[A-Za-z]*;?)[^']*'>(.*?)</p>
```

Replacement:

```
<p style='$1'>$2</p>
```

It's not particularly efficient or necessarily the best way to do it. Subtle bugs would be if the `<p>` tag contains another nested `<p>` (I'm pretty sure this isn't valid mark-up, but thought it best to mention anyway) since it would match the closing `</p>` of the nested `<p>` instead of the outer one we're trying to match.

Another potential bug is that it will mess up if there are nested escaped single quotes inside the `style` element, such as `style='attr=\'value\';text-align:center;'`. This is possible to fix with a more complicated regular expression, but at the risk of making it pretty unreadable.

In my opinion, a solution involving parsing would be a lot better, such as NiftyDude's suggestion with javascript.